# DomDocument Validate Error formatting

Tags: php, validation, error-handling, domdocument

I've gone through about 10 other threads but haven't seen anything about this actual issue. The error I'm expecting but I want to be able to output the errors it gives. I know I can suppress these errors by changing the conditional to `if(@$sxml->validate()) {` but then I don't get the errors which I need.

```
$sxml = new DOMDocument;
$sxml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$sxml->formatOutput = true;
$sxml->Load($file . '.xml');
if($sxml->validate()) {
     //doesn't matter it's valid
} else {
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $errors = libxml_get_errors();
    if(!empty($errors)) {
        foreach($errors as $error) {
            echo $error . '<br />';
        }
    }
    libxml_clear_errors();
}
```

Which gives me

> Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): Element test content does not follow the DTD, expecting (this) got (that) Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): Element test content does not follow the DTD, expecting (this) got (that)Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): Element test content does not follow the DTD, expecting (this) got (that)Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): Element test content does not follow the DTD, expecting (this) got (that)

Is there a way to iterate through each error and output it separately though? Nothing in the `else` is outputting that either that is all from the `$sxml->validate()` call.

e.g.

> 1. Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): Element test content does not follow the DTD, expecting (this) got (that)
> 2. Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): Element test content does not follow the DTD, expecting (this) got (that)
> 3. Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): Element test content does not follow the DTD, expecting (this) got (that)
> 4. Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): Element test content does not follow the DTD, expecting (this) got (that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [schaffhirt](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.validate.php#85792)'s comment in PHP manual of `DOMDocument::validate`. It contains a class that does exactly that:

```
<?php
    class MyDOMDocument {
        private $_delegate;
        private $_validationErrors;

        public function __construct (DOMDocument $pDocument) {
            $this->_delegate = $pDocument;
            $this->_validationErrors = array();
        }

        public function __call ($pMethodName, $pArgs) {
            if ($pMethodName == "validate") {
                $eh = set_error_handler(array($this, "onValidateError"));
                $rv = $this->_delegate->validate();
                if ($eh) {
                    set_error_handler($eh);
                }
                return $rv;
            }
            else {
                return call_user_func_array(array($this->_delegate, $pMethodName), $pArgs);
            }
        }
        public function __get ($pMemberName) {
            if ($pMemberName == "errors") {
                return $this->_validationErrors;
            }
            else {
                return $this->_delegate->$pMemberName;
            }
        }
        public function __set ($pMemberName, $pValue) {
            $this->_delegate->$pMemberName = $pValue;
        }
        public function onValidateError ($pNo, $pString, $pFile = null, $pLine = null, $pContext = null) {
            $this->_validationErrors[] = preg_replace("/^.+: */", "", $pString);
        }
    }
?>

<?php
    // $doc is a DOMDocument object
    $myDoc = new MyDOMDocument($doc); // copy constructor

    // do anything with $myDoc that you would with $doc

    $isValid = $myDoc->validate(); // won't create warnings
    if (!$isValid) {
        print_r($myDoc->errors); // the array all warnings are collected in
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, accepted. I completely skipped over the comments when I was on that page. I figured that would have been a built in option and I was misusing something.